# for each result that = 1 add cell to table row?

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

```
<?
// Set the MySQL Configuration
$db_host       = "test";
$db_user       = "test";
$db_password   = "test";
$db_name       = "test";
$db_table      = "test";

// Start Connection
$db_connect        =  mysql_connect ($db_host, $db_user, $db_password);

// Select Database
$db_select        =  mysql_select_db ($db_name, $db_connect);


$query = "SELECT bird_owner, place_name, funds, place_description FROM bird_locations";

$query2 = "SELECT blue_bird, red_bird, green_bird, gold_bird, black_bird FROM bird_locations"; 

// this query ($query2) is to select just the birds so can check if any bird = 1 then add a new image cell in table

// Execution MySQL Query
$result = mysql_query($query);


if($result)
{

// table headers

echo '<table width="90%" border="0" align="center" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="10">


<p><p><p>
<tr>
<th align="center"><b>Owner</b></th>
<th align="center"><b>PlaceName</b></th>
<th align="center"><b>Birds</b></th>
<th align="center"><b>Funds</b></th>
<th align="center"><b>Description</b></th>
</tr>
';

//now i add a new row for each result which works.

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
 {
     echo '<tr>
    <td align="center"><b>' . $row['bird_owner'].'</b></td>
    <td align="center"><b>' . $row['place_name'].'</b></td>

    <td align="center"><b><img src="bird_blue_50px.png"/></b></td> 

    <td align="center"><b>' . $row['funds'].'L$</b></td>
    <td align="center"><b>' . $row['place_description'].'</b></div></td>

    </tr>';

 }

echo '</table>';

}


//Close MySQL connection
mysql_close($db_connect);
?>
```

When the rows are generated the 3rd cell of a row is an image of a bird, but how can I make it so that if the value of a bird in the database is 1 that it shows an extra cell for another bird image?

e.g. if

- blue_bird value equals 1 show image in row
- red_bird value equals 1 show a red bird image in row also
- green_bird value equals 1 show green bird image
- gold_bird value equals show gold bird image
- black_bird value equals show black bird image

and if there value equals 0 then don't show that image in table

Comment: Try first, ask second. This community is for helping to solve specific problems, not for doing your work for you. (Although you seem to have gotten lucky this time).

Comment: @RobMasters actually i have tried different approaches eg for loops and if else and other conditions but i didnt think it relevant to post multiple code and clutter the question ty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the echo:

```
echo '<tr>
<td align="center"><b>' . $row['bird_owner'].'</b></td>
<td align="center"><b>' . $row['place_name'].'</b></td>';
if ($row['blue_bird']==1){
   echo '<td>Etc...';
}

echo '<td align="center"><b><img src="bird_blue_50px.png"/></b></td> 

<td align="center"><b>' . $row['funds'].'L$</b></td>
<td align="center"><b>' . $row['place_description'].'</b></div></td>

</tr>';
```

Also, mysql_query won't be supported for long anymore: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Comment: I've been noticing this recently as well.... answers to long closed questions that get up-voted immediately...

Comment: Well sorry for trying to help -_-